# useEffect not triggered

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I'm trying to use redux with useEffect to update/get the redux state but useEffect is totally not running at all but I have no idea what is going on. I can't even get the "hi"

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setDisplayLogsheet, getLogsheets } from '../redux/actions';   

...

const { displayLogsheet, logsheets } = useSelector(state => state.logsheetReducer);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hi")
    dispatch(getLogsheets());
    dispatch(setDisplayLogsheet(logsheets));
}, []);
```

Any help please? Thanks

---

UPDATE: here's more code to understand

App.js:

I have added the store inside the provider

```js
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    export default function App() {
      return(
        <Provider store={Store}>
          <NavigationContainer>
          ...
       <Provider />

    }
```

home.js:

tried to useSelector to get the logsheets and displayLogsheets and useEffect to dispatch, **but the the useEffect is totally not running**

```js
    export default function Home({navigation})  {
        
        const { displayLogsheet, logsheets } = useSelector(state => state.logsheetReducer);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log('getting logsheets...')
            dispatch(getLogsheets())
          }, [dispatch])
          
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log('setting displayLogsheet...')
            if(logsheets){ 
                dispatch(setDisplayLogsheet(logsheets))
            }
        }, [dispatch, logsheets])
    
    
        console.log(logsheets)
        console.log(displayLogsheet)

        return (
            <>

            <SafeAreaView>
                <ScrollView>
                    <HomeTopStack logsheet={displayLogsheets} iterateDocket={iterateDocket} />
                    <ScanBarcodeButton navigation={navigation} />
                    {displayLogsheets.data.DO.map(logsheet => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', logsheet)}>
                            <DOCards logsheet={displayLogsheets} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
            </>
        )
    }
```

store.js:

```js
    import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import logsheetReducer from './reducers';
    
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({ logsheetReducer });
    
    export const Store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

reducer.js:

this is the reducer to set display logsheet and also to get the dummy logsheet data

```js
    import { SET_DISPLAY_LOGSHEET, GET_LOGSHEETS } from "./actions";
    
    const initialState = {
        logsheets: {},
        displayLogsheet: {},
    }
    
    function logsheetReducer(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case SET_DISPLAY_LOGSHEET:
                console.log("inside logsheetReducer, SET_DISPLAY_LOGSHEET")
                return { ...state, displayLogsheet: action.payload };
            case GET_LOGSHEETS:
                console.log("inside logsheetReducer, GET_LOGSHEET")
                return { ...state, logsheets: action.payload };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    
    export default logsheetReducer;
```

actions.js:

```js
    import CreateFakeLogsheets from "../data/logsheet";
    
    export const SET_DISPLAY_LOGSHEET = 'SET_DISPLAY_LOGSHEET';
    export const GET_LOGSHEETS = 'GET_LOGSHEETS';
    
    const logsheets = CreateFakeLogsheets(2,3)
    
    export const getLogsheets = () => {
        console.log("inside getLogsheets")
        try {
            return dispatch => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_LOGSHEETS,
                    payload: logsheets
                })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    
    export const setDisplayLogsheet = displayLogsheet => {
        console.log("inside setDisplayLogsheets")
    
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_DISPLAY_LOGSHEET,
                payload: displayLogsheet
            });
        }
    };
```

here's most of the code with redux and also the useEffect. Any help please

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the code? This effect should run once, unless something is wrong elsewhere. Although, you shouldn't exclude dependencies from the dependency array. `dispatch` and `logsheets` belong in there.

Comment: More codes added, any help please

Comment: I just have to ask, since that part of the code is not in the example. But you did import useEffect in the Home component, right? I simply cannot see why it wouldn't run, from looking at this code...

Comment: Yes, I did import it like this "import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';". I could not understand as well. Could it possible because of the version problem?

Comment: The thing with useEffect is, that is runs on every single render, unless there is a dependency array, and none of the dependencies changed. You could try to completely remove the whole dependency array, I mean with the square brackets and all, and see if it runs then. But in any case, the useEffect should run once, when the component mounts. Are you sure this is not the case? Once you know it runs at least once, you can start narowing down why it doesn't run every time it should.

And if you're sure it doesn't even run once, that means the component simply isn't mounted (I think)

Comment: You could try adding an `alert('useEffect runs!')` inside the useEffect, that will be impossible to miss, unlike a console.log that might disappear because there's so much else being logged. Or add a breakpoint inside the useEffect.

Comment: One more thing. I think useEffect runs after the component has rendered, so potentially, if there is an error during render, it might stop the whole thing before it gets to useEffect. Look out for any errors, find the source, and correct it. Maybe this is obvious, but sometimes we overlook the obvious stuff :)

Comment: Sorry for the "spam", but I was too late to edit the previous comment. You could also try swapping useEffect for useLayoutEffect, since this will run a bit earlier, before the component is "painted" in the browser window.

Comment: Also, one thing I think you should seriously consider, since you're already using Redux, is to use Redux Toolkit with RTK Query. It will simplify your fetching logic, and you will thank yourself later. That is, if you have a choice. I'm in this situation myself, working with an old code base with lots of spaghetti code and badly implemented Redux. I'd love to clean up the mess, but it's not all up to me.

Comment: hey @GøranCantona thank you so much for your patiences and explainations. Your comments last night gave me an idea so I tested the code and find out that there's no problem using useEffect and useSelector, BUT the problem is when I use the state variable displayLogsheet inside the html component, then it will not enter the useEffect. Maybe it's just like what u mentioned just now, it has error stopping it to enter the useEffect, but I don't see any error inside. ANYWAY, I manage to find out what's the problem, it's accessing the state variable issue

Comment: but one thing that can confirm is that when I did not use displayLogsheet variable, everythings works just fine

Comment: is it possible to use the Redux Toolkit with RTK Query to fetch the state variables? @GøranCantona

Comment: RTK Query lets you define "api endpoints" that will generate hooks you can use inside your components, to access the fetched data. It comes with automatic caching, so that you can access this in different components without fetching again, and cache invalidation if you perform specific updates. Read more about it here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how the rest of the code is structured, I would split the effect in two, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('getting logsheets...')
  dispatch(getLogsheets())
}, [dispatch])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('setting displayLogsheet...')
  if(logsheets){ // only dispatch this if logsheets have been fetched
    dispatch(setDisplayLogsheets(logsheets))
  }
}, [dispatch, logsheets])
```

Comment: the two comments not even showing :(

Comment: That is weird. Are you sure your component is actually rendered? Add a console.log outside of the useEffect, and see if that is ever logging anything

Comment: yes it's being rendered, in fact not sure why it's being rendered twice. I have update the post with more codes.